# how can I allow the user to click only 3 times on a button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a little rock paper scissors game. for that I've written a small javascript in jquery. the whole thing should work like this: user presses button, an ajax event is fired, the selected option is added to a div and a counter increments. but only 3 times! I can't figure it out to work like this... here's my code

```
if (counter <= 3){
    $('.buStein1').click(function(event){
        $.post("game.php", { uid: "<?php echo $user['id']?>", choice: "stein", runde: counter  });
        $('#choiceContainer').append(stein);
        counter++;
      });
    $('.buSchere1').click(function(event){
        $.post("game.php", { uid: "<?php echo $user['id']?>", choice: "schere", runde: counter  });
        $('#choiceContainer').append(schere);
        counter++;
      });
    $('.buPapier1').click(function(event){
        $.post("game.php", { uid: "<?php echo $user['id']?>", choice: "papier", runde: counter  });
        $('#choiceContainer').append(papier);
        counter++;
      });
}
else {
    $('#choiceContainer').text('no clicking possible');
}
```

Comment: What's your specific problem? Looks fine other than I don't see an original declaration of "counter".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all define your counter outside the functions:

```
var counter = 0;
```

Then check counter within the click event handlers prior to doing anything else:

```
$('.buStein1').click(function(event){
    if (checkCounter()) {
      $.post("game.php", { uid: "<?php echo $user['id']?>", choice: "stein", runde: counter  });
      $('#choiceContainer').append(stein);
    }
  });
$('.buSchere1').click(function(event){
    if (checkCounter()) {
      $.post("game.php", { uid: "<?php echo $user['id']?>", choice: "schere", runde: counter  });
      $('#choiceContainer').append(schere);
    }
  });
$('.buPapier1').click(function(event){
    if (checkCounter()) {
      $.post("game.php", { uid: "<?php echo $user['id']?>", choice: "papier", runde: counter  });
      $('#choiceContainer').append(papier);
    }
  });


function checkCounter() 
{
  if (counter > 3)
  {
    $('#choiceContainer').text('no clicking possible');
    return false;
  }

  counter++;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `if (counter <= 3)` check should be inside the `click` function.

At the moment you're *binding the click event* if the counter is less than three.